# typeDefs must contain only strings, documents, schemas, or functions, got object

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, express-graphql

I am working on an express apollo server and structured all the graphql types like below:

[image]

I am using 'graphql-tools/load-files' and 'graphql-tools/merge' for merging all the types. My index.js file is like belwo:

```
const path = require('path');
const { loadFilesSync } = require('@graphql-tools/load-files');
const { mergeTypeDefs } = require('@graphql-tools/merge');
const types = loadFilesSync(path.join(__dirname, '.'), { recursive: true })
const typeDefs = mergeTypeDefs(types);
module.exports = { typeDefs };
```

When I run the project I, get the following error:

```
Error: typeDefs must contain only strings, documents, schemas, or functions, got object
```

The code worked normally on a previous project. But when I started a new project deleting previous node modules and fresh npm install, I face this weird issue. How can I get rid of it ?

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution to the problem. I had to remove the { recursive: true } and add { extensions: ['gql'] .  Here it is:

```
const path = require('path');
const { loadFilesSync } = require('@graphql-tools/load-files');
const { mergeTypeDefs } = require('@graphql-tools/merge');
const typesArray = loadFilesSync(path.join(__dirname, '.'), { extensions: ['gql'] });
const typeDefs = mergeTypeDefs(types);
module.exports = { typeDefs };
```